# Java set transparency on Color.color WITHOUT using rgb's

Tags: java, colors

I'm woundering, is there a way to set transparency on a color without using rgb's. For example you can do this

```
Color color = new Color(255,255,255,Transparency)
```

but I want to use it this way

```
Color = new Color(Color.red,Transparency)
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't make my colorChooser return a rgb value that I need to make the color transparent aperently. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Transparency is a range between 0-254, so passing "Transparency" doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any such method or constructor at the moment, but it's dead easy to write a helper method:

```
public static Color newColorWithAlpha(Color original, int alpha) {
    return new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), alpha);
}
```

You can import that statically, at which point you'd have:

```
Color color = newColorWithAlpha(Color.red, alpha);
```